# What is the best way to declare many variables at once for a single function?

Tags: c++, variable-declaration

I wanted to use a function to search through a list of possible message values. E.g, a message may be '01 02 03' hex, and then I will check against possible messages if it is any of those.

What I don't know is where it is best to declare variables in this case. Taking into account that I am using a function, if I declare all possible messages within the function it is going to be 25 messages getting declared and defined every time we receive a new message, which may be quite often.

Otherwise, I was told not to use global variables so I am a bit troubled, also considering that my function is in a separate cpp file to the main, with its own header.

Whats the general way to go about this? Is it okay to declare a lot of local variables whenever accessing this function?

Comment: I think you may have been told something too simplistic concerning global variables (or potentially you misunderstood). Having global **constants**, especially inside an isolated translation unit, is fine.

Comment: Having a lot of unnecessary global variables is one thing, global constants is another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the possible message values in a static variable in the function. It will be initialized only once the first time you call the function. Example with `std::vector`:

```
void f() {
    static const std::vector<std::string> v{"\x010203", "\x040506"};
}
```

If the initialization process is more complicated you can use a separate function to do it:

```
auto create_message_values() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    // initialize values
    return v;
}

void f() {
    static const auto v = create_message_values();
}
```

Or with a lambda:

```
 void f() {
        static const auto v = [](){
            std::vector<std::string> v;
            // initialize values
            return v;
        };
    }
```

You can use any container that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go about this and it depends on the implementation of the function and whether this just a single function that needs access to the table of messages or multiple functions.

The two approaches used with C or C++ are to specify a visibility scope commensurate with the needs of accessing the data:

- static list in the single function that needs the list restricting visibility to the scope of the function
- static list in the source file for the multiple functions that needs the list restricting visibility to the scope of the source file

For C++ using a `class` to encapsulate as static, private data is an appropriate alternative. The function may be exposed as a static member of the class or as a functor using the `()` operator.

Since you are going to be doing table lookup for each message processed, you should consider how the list is stored and the search method used to do the list lookup. With 25 messages using a simple lookup such as binary search can make a difference in the overhead of processing each message.

Being able to do searches by comparing multiple bytes at a time can also be a significant boost in performance. And if there is a single message type that composes the majority of the message stream then ruling that message type out with a simple comparison before doing a lookup of the message in the table/list may be huge performance gains.

However considerations of search performance should be tempered by considerations for the rest of the processing done for each message. If the lookup time is only a small part of the total processing time then simplicity will be the best alternative.